# Three-level meta-analysis variance in R

Tags: r, metafor

I am running a three-level meta-analysis in R using Metafor and when I try to test the variance at all three levels I get NA. I attach the syntax I have used with the model and the analyses of variance within and between studies.

```
overall<-rma.mv(yi,vi,random=list(~1|effectsizeID,~1|studyID),tdist=TRUE,data=data2)
Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 240; method: REML)

   logLik   Deviance        AIC        BIC       AICc   
-3643.320   7286.639   7292.639   7303.068   7292.741   

Variance Components:

           estim   sqrt  nlvls  fixed        factor 
sigma^2.1  0.564  0.751     16     no  effectsizeID 
sigma^2.2  0.269  0.518     89     no       studyID 

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 239) = 31935.762, p-val < .001

Model Results:

estimate     se   tval   df   pval  ci.lb  ci.ub    
   0.498  0.200  2.494  239  0.013  0.105  0.891  * 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
modelnovar<-rma.mv(yi,vi,random=list(~1|effectsizeID,~1|studyID),sigma2=c(0,NA),tdist=TRUE,data=data2)
        df        AIC        BIC       AICc      logLik        LRT   pval 
Full     3  7292.6390  7303.0684  7292.7411  -3643.3195                   
Reduced  2 21157.3173 21164.2703 21157.3682 -10576.6587 13866.6783 <.0001 
                QE 
Full    31935.7621 
Reduced 31935.7621 

modelnovar2<-rma.mv(yi,vi,random=list(~1|effectsizeID,~1|studyID),sigma2=c(NA,0),tdist=TRUE,data=data2)
      df        AIC        BIC       AICc     logLik       LRT   pval 
Full     3  7292.6390  7303.0684  7292.7411 -3643.3195                  
Reduced  2 14658.0785 14665.0315 14658.1294 -7327.0393 7367.4395 <.0001 
                QE 
Full    31935.7621 
Reduced 31935.7621 

n<-length(data2$vi)
list.inverse.variances<-1/(data2$vi)
sum.inverse.variances<-sum(list.inverse.variances)
squared.sum.inverse.variances<-(sum.inverse.variances)^2
list.inverse.variances.square<-1/(data2$vi^2)
sum.inverse.variances.square<-sum(list.inverse.variances.square)
numerator<-(n-1)*sum.inverse.variances
denominator<-squared.sum.inverse.variances-sum.inverse.variances.square
estimated.sampling.variance<-numerator/denominator

I2_1<-(estimated.sampling.variance)/(overall$sigma2[1]
+ overall$sigma2[2]+estimated.sampling.variance)
I2_2 <- (overall$sigma2[1])/(overall$sigma2[1]
+ overall$sigma2[2]+estimated.sampling.variance)
I2_3 <- (overall$sigma2[2])/(overall$sigma2[1]
+ overall$sigma2[2]+estimated.sampling.variance)

amountvariancelevel1<-I2_1*100
amountvariancelevel2<-I2_2*100
amountvariancelevel3<-I2_3*100

amountvariancelevel1
NA
amountvariancelevel2
NA
amountvariancelevel3
NA
```

I tried to test how the variability is distributed over the three levels as it appears to be both within and between-study variability, but I don't get any result.